# Python - How do I do conditional counting of rows based on various columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, count, conditional-statements

I want to create a Python dataframe that counts the number of times that the types *C* **or** *P* occur for each date in each sample. C and P are subsets of F meaning that whenever *Type* is equal to *F*, I can count the number of rows with the same *Sample* value and the same *Date* value.
I cannot hardcode the conditions as the actual data set is much larger than the sample. This means that I need to base my conditions on the values in the data set where *Type* is equal to *F*.
Here is a sample of my data set, df_Data (the actual one being much larger):

> Sample | Type | Date | Strike
>       A      | F | 1 Jun 2020 |
>       A | C | 1 Jun 2020 | 5
>       A | P | 1 Jun 2020 | 2.5
>       A | F | 1 Dec 2020 |
>       A | P | 1 Dec 2020 | 3
>       A | P | 1 Dec 2020 | 3.5
>       A | P | 1 Dec 2020 | 4
>       B | F | 1 Jun 2020 |
>       B | C | 1 Jun 2020 | 2.5
>       B | C | 1 Jun 2020 | 3
>       B | C | 1 Jun 2020 | 4
>       B | F | 1 Dec 2020 |
>       B | C | 1 Dec 2020 | 2
>       B | C | 1 Dec 2020 | 4
>       B | P | 1 Dec 2020 | 2
>       B | P | 1 Dec 2020 | 4

The corresponding output is a new dataframe like this one:

Sample | Type | Date | Count

=======================

```
A | F | 1 Jun 2020 |2
A | F | 1 Dec 2020 |3
B | F | 1 Jun 2020 |3
B | F | 1 Dec 2020 |4
```

In Excel I would have used the CountIfs-function:
IF Type = "F" then countifs(Sample-column, Sample-value, Date-column, Date-value, Type-column, "<> F")

Please help (apologies for the poor table formatting).

Comment: How do you want to implement this?  In a relational database (like mySQL)?  What (if any) programming language are you using?  Please update your tags.

Comment: I made some edits based on FoggyDay's questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df['Type']=df['Type'].apply(lambda x: 'F' if x == 'P' or 'C' else '')
adf = df.groupby(['Sample', 'Type', 'Dat`enter code here`e'],as_index=False).agg({'Strike':['count']})
```

This code reads `sample.csv` into a dataframe. Then, you perform a lambda-query on the column `Type`.  The final result is in `adf`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are likely to be downvoted or deleted altogether. I edit your post a bit, feel free to expand more. For more guidance, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the required output based on the logic provided by @Umesh Sharma.
From the original dataframe, *df*, I created a dataframe without any of the *F* rows.

```
df_no_F = df[df['Type'] != "F"]
```

I then use groupby and count to determine the number of rows for each
*Sample* and *Date* combination.

```
df_count = df_no_F.groupby(['Sample' , 'Date'], as_index=False).count()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do this. Use `df.loc` to filter down to the desired Types and then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) :)

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Getting a df in the right form
s = """Sample | Type | Date | Strike
A | F | 1 Jun 2020 |
A | C | 1 Jun 2020 | 5
A | P | 1 Jun 2020 | 2.5
A | F | 1 Dec 2020 |
A | P | 1 Dec 2020 | 3
A | P | 1 Dec 2020 | 3.5
A | P | 1 Dec 2020 | 4
B | F | 1 Jun 2020 |
B | C | 1 Jun 2020 | 2.5
B | C | 1 Jun 2020 | 3
B | C | 1 Jun 2020 | 4
B | F | 1 Dec 2020 |
B | C | 1 Dec 2020 | 2
B | C | 1 Dec 2020 | 4
B | P | 1 Dec 2020 | 2
B | P | 1 Dec 2020 | 4"""
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='|'))
df.columns = [i.strip() for i in df.columns]
for col in ['Sample', 'Type', 'Date']:
    df[col] = df[col].str.strip()

# Meat and bones of this operation
new_df = df.loc[(df['Type'] == 'C') | (df['Type'] == 'P')].groupby(['Sample', 'Date'])['Strike'].count().reset_index()

# Reformat to desired output
new_df['Type'] = 'F'
new_df = new_df[df.columns].rename(columns={'Strike': 'Count'}).sort_values(by=['Sample', 'Date'], ascending=[True, False])
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  Sample Type        Date  Count
1      A    F  1 Jun 2020      2
0      A    F  1 Dec 2020      3
3      B    F  1 Jun 2020      3
2      B    F  1 Dec 2020      4
```